# message broker consumer/producer with reassign when client goes down?

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue

I am looking for a message broker API to use it with c#.

Normally the things are quite simple. I have a server that knows what jobs are to do and I have some clients that need to get these jobs.

And here are the special requirements I have:

- If a client got a job but fails to answer within a specific time, then another client should do the work.
- More than one queue and priorities
- If possible it needs to work with big message queues (this way I could just load all jobs sometimes a month and forget about it
- secured communications would be good.
- API for talking with the broker from c#. How much work is done? What is still to do?
  Delete some jobs...
- If available replication to another broker would be good.
- The broker needs to run on windows

What is not an issue:

- low latency (there is no problem when a message needs minutes)

Do you know such a message broker that is free to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and several other AMQP implementations satisfy most of (if not all of) these requirements.

- RabbitMQ allows clients to acknowledge receipt and/or processing of messages.  As per http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#message-acknowledge:

> If a consumer dies without sending an acknowledgement the AMQP broker
>   will redeliver it to another consumer or, if none are available at the
>   time, the broker will wait until at least one consumer is registered
>   for the same queue before attempting redelivery.

- Many queues (and in fact many brokers) are supported, in a variety of different configurations
- It scales particularly well, even for very large message queues: http://www.rabbitmq.com/faq.html#performance
- Encryption is supported: http://www.rabbitmq.com/faq.html#channel-encryption
- There is a .NET Client Users Guide and API docs: http://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
- There is live failover if a broker dies: http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html
- It runs on Windows, Linux, and probably anything else that has an Erlang implementation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. RabbitMQ does not support priorities. I will try ActiveMQ now.

Comment: Priorities can be approximated using multiple queues.  For a description of how to do that, see http://dougbarth.github.com/2011/07/01/approximating-priority-with-rabbitmq.html